# Android shared preferences names

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I can obtain SharedPreferences via:

```
getSharedPreferences("someName", ...)
```

How do I get a list of all names of shared preferences in my application?

If it's not possible via code, is there any way to do it via adb (without root)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's no API for this, the only way is to list files in `shared_prefs` directory. Something like:

```
File sharedPrefsDir = new File(getFilesDir(), "../shared_prefs");
File[] files = sharedPrefsDir.listFiles();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the preferences.xml from `/data/data/(package)/shared_prefs/(package)_preferences.xml`

Comment: It's a file which contains default preferences. That's not what I've asked about.